# Radio Group android

Tags: android, radio-button

I started to develop for Android few days ago and I got stuck trying to use Radio Group. In my code for some reason all of the radio buttons can be selected together.

Any suggestion?

xml:

```
<RadioGroup
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/rG">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="89dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <RadioButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="95"
      android:layout_marginLeft="75sp"
      android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
      android:id="@+id/rb95"
      android:layout_gravity="left|top"
      android:checked="true"/>

    <RadioButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="98"
      android:id="@+id/rb98"
      android:layout_gravity="right|top"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rb95"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rbs"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rbs"/>

     <RadioButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="96"
      android:id="@+id/rb96"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:layout_below="@id/rb95"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@id/rb95"
      android:layout_alignStart="@id/rb95"/>

    <RadioButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="soler"
      android:id="@+id/rbs"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
      android:layout_alignTop="@id/rb96"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the RadioButtons out of the RelativeLayout (get completely rid of it: it's not only misplaced, but also useless) and they will work as expected.

If you really need the RelativeLayout as a container for the RadioGroup, then swap the RelativeLayout and RadioGroup (RelativeLayout on the **outside**)

Comment: the problem i had with removing the relative layout is that i want the 4 buttons in 2 by 2 square is there other way to do it?

Comment: ... put 2 vertical RadioGroups side by side?

Comment: but i want them to be in the same group

Comment: Sorry, you can't have them in the same group. Radiogroup inherits from LinearLayout, so it's "all horizontal" or "all vertical". Not splitted. Maybe there's some open source library made by someone on github, for this? Or you could have fun editing Google's source for the RadioGroup component, but I guess it's a bit hard to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have a `relativeLayout` inside your `RadioGroup`.
[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html) is the Google Developer page on **radio buttons**.

Comment: the problem i had with removing the relative layout is that i want the 4 buttons in 2 by 2 square is there other way to do it?

Comment: Sure, you could use flags to check which buttons are clicked. The group is just for convenience but you can program each button and place two by two or all four if you really want to